# Pattern lookahead

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ma)|([a-zA-Z_]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ma");
m.find();
System.out.println("1 " + m.group(1) + ""); //ma
System.out.println("2 " + m.group(2)); // null
Matcher m = p.matcher("mad");
m.find();
System.out.println("1 " + m.group(1) + ""); //ma
System.out.println("2 " + m.group(2)); // null
```

But I need that the string "mad" would be in the 2nd group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like:

```
(ma(?!d))|([a-zA-Z_]+)
```

from "perldoc perlre":

> "(?!pattern)"
>                    A zero-width negative look-ahead assertion.  For
>   example
>                    "/foo(?!bar)/" matches any occurrence of "foo" that
>   isn't
>                    followed by "bar".

the only thing I'm not sure about is whether Java supports this syntax, but I think it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `matches` instead of `find`, it will try to match the entire string against that pattern, which it can only do by putting `mad` in the second group:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(ma)|([a-zA-Z_]+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("ma"); 
        m.matches();
        System.out.println("1 " + m.group(1)); // ma
        System.out.println("2 " + m.group(2)); // null
        m = p.matcher("mad"); 
        m.matches();
        System.out.println("1 " + m.group(1)); // null
        System.out.println("2 " + m.group(2)); // mad
    }
}
```

Comment: In my situation I cannot use match. I think I need something to look ahead in my pattern.

Comment: Can you use `(ma)$|([a-zA-Z_]+)$`? That will again force it to get to the end of the string, and `find` will still work.

Comment: In my task I have a long string where is a lot of lexemes for this patterns that is why I use find not match.

Comment: @itun: Perhaps you could give us more information about what you actually need to do, if neither of the solutions I've provided so far will work? If you need to match more than one value in the string, please provide some sample strings and expected outputs.